# 2 collections loop same time

Tags: vb.net, collections

Hi am making my first steps with strucrures and collections, I have created 2 collections using the same structure.

One collection holds data for this year and the other last.

is it possible it iterate through both at the same time?

```
Structure dateControl

   Dim StartDate As Date
   Dim EndDate As Date
   Dim weekCount As Integer
   Dim YearWeek As Integer

End Structure

Dim LastYearStruct As dateControl

    For I = 1 To howmanyweeks

        LastYearStruct.StartDate = DateAdd(DateInterval.WeekOfYear, I - 1, dateFirstSunday)
        LastYearStruct.EndDate = DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, 7, LastYearStruct.StartDate)
        LastYearStruct.weekCount = I
        LastYearStruct.YearWeek = I

        lastYear.Add(LastYearStruct)

    Next

Dim ThisYearStruct As dateControl

    For I = 1 To howmanyweeks

        ThisYearStruct.StartDate = DateAdd(DateInterval.WeekOfYear, I - 1, dateFirstSunday)
        ThisYearStruct.EndDate = DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, 7, ThisYearStruct.StartDate)
        ThisYearStruct.weekCount = I
        ThisYearStruct.YearWeek = I

        ThisYear.Add(ThisYearStruct)

    Next
```

I was trying something like

for each thing in thisyear and lastyear

debug.print thing

next

thanks for any help

Comment: If they have the same number of items then just loop on on integer and refer bring them up by ordinal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manually iterate through the collections simultaneously.

```
    Dim lastYearEnumerator = lastYear.GetEnumerator()
    Dim thisYearEnumerator = ThisYear.GetEnumerator()
    Do While lastYearEnumerator.MoveNext AndAlso thisYearEnumerator.MoveNext
        Dim lastYearThing = lastYearEnumerator.Current
        Dim thisYearThing = thisYearEnumerator.Current

        ' do stuff with things
    Loop
```

This will iterate through both collections until the end of either collection has been reached.

Comment: both these methods work, but think I am missing something as how do I get StartDate variable out of lastYearThing??  I keep looking but can't figure but if I insert a breakpoint and the tooltips pops up I can expand into the variables so easy?

Comment: Don't why but the intellisense didn't give my the variables names manually typed them in and it works many thanks to everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Just use a For loop

```
For i As Integer = 1 To lastYear.Length
    Dim lastYearThing = lastYear(i)
    Dim thisYearThing = thisYear(i)
    ' ...
Next
```